# How to use `docker-machine create` so that the docker engine listens on a custom port?

Tags: docker, port, docker-machine

My service provider does not allow me to connect to docker on port 2376. Is there a flag for docker-machine to set up docker on host to listen on another port but 2376 so that commands like

docker-machine ls
 OR
docker-machine env

work? Now they fail because after creation of docker on the host the daemon starts on port 2376 which is not accessible. Sure, I could manually change that port after creation but then the mentioned commands are not aware to connect to the docker daemon on that host on another port but 2376.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a flag for docker-machine to set up docker on host to listen on another port but 2376

yes, use the `-H` or `--host` option of the [`docker daemon`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/) command. To make your Docker daemon listen on port 443 (which should be open all most firewalls), start your docker daemon with:

```
docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:443
```

If your docker host operating system is Debian or Ubuntu, you can set this in the `/etc/default/docker` file by adding the line `DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:443"`.

If you are using RedHat or CentOS, add `OPTIONS=-H tcp://0.0.0.0:443` to the `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file.

---

### Using docker-machine

To install a Docker engine with a custom `--host` option, you would use docker machine with the [`--engine-opt` option](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/create/#specifying-configuration-options-for-the-created-docker-engine):

```
docker-machine create --engine-opt host=tcp://0.0.0.0:443 ...
```

Then when you use `docker-machine env ...` you will note that the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable will still be set with the default port `2376`, but now you can override it with `443` and it will work.

Unfortunately this won't allow `docker-machine ls` to work as the `2376` value for the docker engine port is hardcoded in docker-machine drivers. If you really want to get `docker-machine ls` to work for a different port, the easiest way would be to duplicate one of the [docker-machine driver source file](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/e143c68cf9865cf0344b8a0ef5f8d402bced19fd/drivers/generic/generic.go#L140) that you use and hardcode a different port ; then compile a new docker-machine binary with your new driver.

---

Let's say the IP address of the remote server is 11.22.33.44.

```sh
# create the docker engine using the generic Machine driver
docker-machine create --engine-opt host=tcp://0.0.0.0:443 --driver=generic --generic-ip-address=11.22.33.44 mytestengine

# prepare the environments so that docker client can connect on port 443
docker-machine env mytestengine
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://11.22.33.44:443

# use docker client as usual
docker version
```

Comment: That does not answer my question as I am looking for a way to configure the creation of docker via docker-machine so that I am able to run commands like docker-machine ls or docker-machine env towards a host on which the docker daemon is not running on standard ports.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Is _How to use `docker-machine create` so that the docker engine listens on a custom port?_ what you are after?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for and that requires a switxh etc. When creating the host with docker-machine so that commands afterwards issued locolly are aware to connect to the docker daemon listening on another port but the default one